# Issues with Facebook and Symfony 1.4

Tags: facebook, symfony-1.4, facebook-timeline

New Facebook and Symfony 1.4 developer with a couple of issues.

First off, I am having an issue with getting the Add to Timeline button to appear on my page where I need it. My site seems to show a Facebook loading image, then after the apparent loading no button is displayed. I've looked around at many different sites (including the FB tutorial for Open Graph), all saying to place the scripts after the opening body tag. I have placed it in my layout.php file so that I do not have to put it in multiple places:

**layout.php**

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
....
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId      : 'APP_ID',
                status     : true, 
                cookie     : true,
                xfbml      : true,
                oauth      : true
            });
        };

        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=APP_ID";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
    <div id="container">
```

I have already replaced APP_ID where appropriate and placed the Add to Timeline button in a view:

**viewSuccess.php**

```php
<?php // Facebook Post-to-Timeline Button for this user's created recipe ?>
<?php if($recipe->getUserId() == sfUserTools::getConnectedUser()->getId()): ?>
    <fb:add-to-timeline show-faces="false" mode="button"></fb:add-to-timeline>
<?php endif ?>
```

I'm not sure if its an issue with where the JSSDK script is placed, or if Symfony is not seeing something in the view page. Note, I do not yet have our app's actions and objects setup for Open Graph, posting to the timeline is not my concern at this time. Any ideas or advice for a newbie?

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas or advice? Maybe because Symfony is setup into different modules instead of just one page, I need to add the JSSDK to each page the button will be on?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to pass the access_token or the perms on the FB.init ?

```
  FB.init({
    appId                : "<?php echo sfConfig::get('app_facebook_api_key') ?>",
    status               : true, // check login status
    cookie               : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml                : false,  // parse XFBML
    perms                : 'read_stream, publish_stream',
    access_token         : "ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE",
    frictionlessRequests : true
  });
```

Comment: Be careful because this button will be deprecated on August 2012. Docs: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#august-2012 

We will be removing the Add to Timeline plugin. If you are embedding the Add to Timeline plugin, we will render the Login Button in its place with the publish_actions permission automatically added to the scope parameter.